# Telegram API Method to start a private chat using a phone number?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Our faculty registers new students by phone number and later follows up with them manually using WhatsApp by registering the contact and then chatting with them.

I want to automate this process with Telegram API since the messages are just typical with minor differences for each specific user, but the problem I'm facing is that there doesn't seem to be a method to directly start a chat with a user using their phone number, only using chat_id.

How can I start a chat using the phone number? And if that's not possible, what would be a better workaround? Ultimately, I wouldn't want the student to subscribe manually to a bot in order to obtain a chat id, just to make the process easier (since they've already registered their personal data including phone number), but if that's the only way to do it I'll take that approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible for a bot to start a conversation and that's by design. Otherwise everyone would constantly receive spam from bots.